# how to solve flutter pub get in flutter 3.0

Tags: android, windows, flutter, dart, mobile

hello I try to run the flutter pub get command in my flutter 3.0 project, but I get this:

Cannot open file, path = 'C:\Users\jorge.ribeiro\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache_temp\dir9616652b\test\fixtures\invalid\n_structure_<.>.json' (OS Error: The syntax of the name of the file, directory name, or volume label is incorrect., error = 123) Running "flutter pub get" in ipartyofficial... pub get failed (66; , errno = 123))

```dart
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel main, 3.1.0-0.0.pre.1035, on Microsoft Windows [versÆo 10.0.19044.1645], locale pt-BR)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[√] VS Code (version 1.67.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability
```

if anyone knows thank you very much !!!!

Comment: are you sure you are running the command in the root dir of your project?

Comment: Yes sure @ 
Abdur Rafay Saleem

Answer (score 0):

This issue appears to be caused by an invalid file name that is being processed by Flutter. File names in Windows cannot contain certain special characters, including `<` and `>`. The error message is indicating that it's trying to open a file with an invalid name.

In your case, it seems that `n_structure_<.>.json` is the problematic file.

As this file appears to be part of your cache (given its location in `AppData\Local\Pub\Cache_temp`), you can try clearing your Flutter pub cache to fix the problem. You can do this by running `flutter pub cache repair` command in your terminal. This command will clean and then download again all packages.

If that doesn't work, try deleting the `Cache_temp` folder directly. This should be safe as it's only a temporary cache, and it will be recreated as needed.

But be aware, these commands can take a while to finish because they re-download all packages again.

Before running the commands, make sure to close your IDE and stop all dart/flutter processes.

Also, consider updating your Flutter to the latest version if you haven't already. There might be bug fixes related to this issue in the newer versions. You can do this by running `flutter upgrade` in your terminal.

Then try running `flutter pub get` again.